Kernel of $A D_1 A^\top$ vs $A D_2 A^\top$
Let $A$ be an arbitrary $m \times n$ matrix, and $D_1$ and $D_2$ are $n \times n$ diagonal matrices. $D_1$ and $D_2$ can have zero entries on the diagonal, but the non-zero pattern is the same.
It the following true?
$$Ker(A D_1 A^\top) = Ker(A D_2 A^\top)$$
I.e., replacing the diagonal matrix with the other one preserves null space.
I feel like it is, but so far I have not succeeded in finding anything related or proving this to myself, nor have I been able to find a counterexample.
If necessary, you can assume that the entries of the diagonal matrices are non-negative.
If it is not true, what properties would the matrices $A$, $D_1$ and $D_2$ need to have for it to be true?
Edit: so after some thinking, it is enough to show this for regular $D_1$ and $D_2$ with positive entries on the diagonal (or any nonzero entries, if we were in complex numbers). That's because there is a matrix $W$ with as many columns as there are non-zeros in the $D$ matrices, such that $D=WW^\top$. Now, we can write $W$ as $W=XY$, where $X$ contains 1 where W has a non-zero, and $Y$ is a square matrix that contains the non-zero values of $W$ on the diagonal. The $X$ matrices are equal for both $D_1$ and $D_2$, the $Y$s differ in values. We can therefore write $D = X Y Y^\top X^\top = X Z X^\top$, so $A D_1 A^\top = A X Z_1 X^\top A = \tilde{A} Z_1 \tilde{A}^\top$, similarly for the second one. $Z$ are now regular matrices with full diagonal of nonzero entries. All singularities are now embedded only in the $\tilde{A}$s.

Edit: context - I want to show that $Ker(B K B^\top) = Ker(B K^+ B^\top)$, where $K$ is SPSD. Since pseudoinverse can be computed using SVD, it boils down to $Ker(B U \Sigma U^\top B^\top) = Ker(B U \Sigma^+ U^\top B^\top)$. There the two matrices differ only by the non-zero values of the diagonals of $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma^+$.

What have you tried? Where did this question come from? Context please

@Mike I don't think it will help much, but I added context to the question. I tried proving it on paper, asking AI chatbots, and tried a few random matrices to see that it really works. No success in determining the truthness of the statement.

Yeah and I tried searching on the Internet, of course, forgot to write that :D

If the entries of the diagonal matrices are non-negative, then this is true.
We can write the matrices $D_i$ as $D_i = D^{\frac{1}{2}}_iD^{\frac{1}{2}}_i$, where $D^{\frac{1}{2}}_i$ is a diagonal matrix whose elements are the square roots of the elements of $D_i$ (in particular, they have the same non-zero pattern). Thus:
$$
AD_iA^\top = AD^{\frac{1}{2}}_i\underbrace{D^{\frac{1}{2}}_iA^\top}_{B^\top} = BB^T. 
$$
Since $\ker\left(BB^\top\right) = \ker\left(B^\top\right)$, we have that $\ker\left(AD_iA^\top\right) = \ker\left(D^{\frac{1}{2}}_iA^\top\right)$. Additionally, we clearly have:
$$
x\in\ker\left(D^{\frac{1}{2}}_iA^\top\right) \iff A^\top x\in\ker\left(D^{\frac{1}{2}}_i\right).
$$
Being $D^{\frac{1}{2}}_i$ diagonal, its kernel is completely determined by the indices of the zero elements on the diagonal; since these indices coincide for $D^{\frac{1}{2}}_1$ and $D^{\frac{1}{2}}_2$, we finally have that:
$$
\ker\left(D^{\frac{1}{2}}_1\right) = \ker\left(D^{\frac{1}{2}}_2\right),
$$
concluding the proof.

nice, thanks, this didn't come to my mind. Just a note why the diagonal entries must be non-negative. I asked a similar question on reddit, and they found a counterexample with A=[1,1;1,1], D1=I, D2=[1,0;0,-1]. This does not work in the proof, since the $Ker(BB^T)=Ker(B^T)$ is not true in complex numbers, which we would have in $D_2^{\frac{1}{2}}$. This is because the $x^\top x=0 \iff x=o$ is not true there.

Thank you for the nice counterexample! I have a hunch that it might also be true if we allow negative elements in $D_i$, but we additionally require that all the signs coincide as well. I'm not sure about how to tackle this though..

I don't think it will work for all negative (or rather non-positive) in $D_i$. We could split $D_i$ to $J E_i J$, where $J=iI$ is a suitably sized identity but with imaginary units, and $E_i$ is all non-negative as before. And now we are again working with complex numbers, but real operations (norm, simple transpose), which is wrong. Moving to complex completely with conjugate transposes is still not right, since now $J \neq J^*$, which we would need.
